# importing function says "x is not a function" but on console log returns function. webpack

Tags: javascript, object, webpack, import, modular

I'm builidng a Battleship game with webpack and trying to make it modular. The problem is that when I import the factory function that creates the players gameboards to my main js file and try to run it webpack throws a compilation error saying that this function is not actually a function, but when I console log the function into the console, the devtools returns a function that creates the object I need. I'm kind of new with this and really don't know whats wrong with it so I would really aprreciate some help. Thank you !
This is the code im importing:

````
const gameBoard = () => {
  const board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

  const ships = [{ name: 'carrier', size: 5 }, { name: 'Battleship', size: 4 }, { name: 'Cruiser', size: 3 }, { name: 'Submarine', size: 3 }, { name: 'Destroyer', size: 2 }]

  const placeShips = () => {
    ships.forEach(ship => function () {
      newShip(ship.name, ship.size)

      let spaces = []

      const lookForSpace = () => {
        const initialPoint = Math.random(0, ((board.length - 1) - ship.size))
        for (let i = initialPoint; i === ship.size; i++) {
          if (gameBoard[i] === '') { spaces.push(i) } else { spaces.push('X') }
        }
      }

      if (spaces.includes('X')) { spaces = []; lookForSpace() } else { spaces.forEach(space => { board[space] = ship.name }) }
    })
  }

  const missedShots = []

  const receiveAttack = (coordenate) => {
    if (board[coordenate] === '') { missedShots.push(coordenate) } else { `${board[coordenate]}`.hit(coordenate) }
  }

  const restartBoard = () => { board.forEach(place => { place = '' }) }

  return ({ board, placeShips, missedShots, receiveAttack, restartBoard })
}

export default { gameBoard } ```

[This is how I call the function and the error it logs, also the function being oged in][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEtr2.png
````

Comment: try `export default gameBoard`

Comment: Do you mean without the curly brackets ? I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

using `export default {gameBoard}` means your default export is `{gameBoard:gameBoard}`

therefore

```
import gameBoard from './?ships.j'
```

results in

```
gameBoard = { gameBoard: function() ..... }
```

to run it, you'd use

```
gameBoard.gameBoard();
```

so, either

```
export default gameBoard;

import gameBoard from './ships.js';
```

or

```
export { gameBoard };

import { gameBoard } from './ships.js';
```

---

there is one other way you could do this if you

```
export default {gameBoard};
```

and it's really only *useful** since top-level `await` has become available. It's not pretty ...

```
const {default:{gameBoard}} = await import('./ships.js');
```

but it does work

---

* I use the term *useful* sarcastically :p

Comment: Wow thanks ! that's a lifesaver. I always believed that using {} was in order to import more than one function at the time, and I was going to add more later on. But now I get it, thank you !

Comment: @TomasGomezBelcastro - I added one more (ugly) possibility